# Interface builder and subclass of UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm using XCode 4.6 and I'm trying to replace one of my UITextView's by a SSTextView from SSToolKit in order to add a placeholder to it. The SSToolkit library is correctly integrated in my project thanks to CocoaPods. So I just changed the type of the property in my view controller to be SSTextView instead of UITextView:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet SSTextView *commentTextView;
```

And of course I also changed the class of the control in interface builder's inspector:

[image]

And yet, in my controller's viewWillAppear: the property is still a UITextView and when I set the placeholder:

```
self.commentTextView.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Comment", @"");
```

I get an "unrecognizable selector setPlaceholder: sent to instance". 
It seems to me like I've done that sort of things a thousand times and yet here, I can't figure out what I'm forgetting.

Comment: I did exactly the same and its working for me. You have imported SSTextView.h in your controller, right?

Comment: Yes I did. That's what I thought. It SHOULD work.

Comment: Try casting it , [(SSTextView *)self.textView setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"Comment", @"")]; and see if it works

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work either. self.commentTextView is still a UITextView and I still get the same error. I'm starting to question the CocoaPods integration.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Maybe you should add the SSTextView.h and SSTextView.m files seperately (https://github.com/soffes/sstoolkit/tree/master/SSToolkit) and then try it (just to see whats causing the problem)

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I just removed SSToolkit from my Podfile, copied SSTextView.h and SSTextView.m directly to my project.... and I get the same result. Now I'm wondering whether it might come from the fact I'm using base internationalization.

Comment: Did you forget to connect the textview and the IBOutlet in IB? I'm using SSTextView the way you describe your situation without any problems whatsoever.

Comment: I double checked and the IBOutlet is connected: http://d.pr/i/pUqo

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It turns out some parts of the compiled application seem not to be overwritten when redeploying to the simulator. So after I deleted the app from the simulator and ran it from scratch, it worked normally. I had other bugs like missing segues and so on so I looked that up and found out about the "delete app" technique. Weird...

Comment: Just in case anybody else finds this: I had to do "Product" -> "Clean" additionally and build/run it again.